# How do I make code "loop - For each" correct?

Tags: vba, excel

I have recently started to use VBA Excel for financial modeling purposes and already found that it can optimize my work process.

Right now I try to develop a macro that will help me to automatically format all the cells in the workbook, and I have no idea how to write such macro.

What I want to do is the following - I have 3 types of numbers:

1. Hard Numbers
2. Numbers that are internal links - they are values from other sheets of the workbook.
3. Numbers that are external links - they are values from other workbooks.

So far i have written this code....

```
 Sub AllLinksAndValuesFormating()
'===============================================
'All links (internal) within this book are blue
'All external links are black and font filled
'All values are like this (# ##0;(# ##0);"-"??)
'===============================================
Dim Criteria_1 As Boolean
Dim Criteria_2 As Boolean

Dim Size As Integer
Size = 8

Dim Style As String
Style = "Arial"

Dim Value As Variant

Criteria_1 = VBA.InStr(1, Value.Formula, ".xls") > 0
Criteria_2 = VBA.InStr(1, Cells.Formula, "!") > 0

    For Each Value In ActiveSheet.Cells

        If IsNumeric(Value) Then

        If Criteria_1 = True Then
        '====================================
        'External Link
        '====================================

            With Selection
                .Font.Color = RGB(38, 38, 38)
                .Font.Name = Style
                .Font.Size = Size
                .Interior.Color = 11402743

                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous

                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlHairline
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlHairline
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlHairline
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlHairline

            End With

        Else

        If Criteria_1 = False And Criteria_2 = True Then
        '====================================
        'Internal link
        '====================================

            With Selection
                .Font.Color = RGB(38, 38, 38)
                .Font.Name = Style
                .Font.Size = Size
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 0

                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous

                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlHairline
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlHairline
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlHairline
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlHairline

            End With
            Else

            End If


    End If
    End If

      Next
End Sub
```

The Error appears here:

```
Criteria_1 = VBA.InStr(1, Value.Formula, ".xls") > 0
```

Error is object required

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do oyu have any code? Here at Stack Overflow, we help each other with specific questions and specific answers. This is not a training site that does free tutoring or free code writing. Be a bit more specific, then you can get better answers.

Comment: Sorry for such an awful effort, thats my first question i have posted here... i will try to do my best. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: You should include the complete errors you see.

Comment: Done________________

Answer (score 1):

I would get the formula of the cell:

```
Cells(1,1).Formula
```

And check that string if it contains any text that indicates external workbook or not.

To know if cell is hard coded or reference you can use

```
 Cells(1,1).HasFormula
```

This will return true or false.

Comment: But how would one know if it has internal or external links ?

Comment: Also you can do an instr() to find out if there is a "\" in the formula, which would mean there is a path in that. Than it is an external reference. Hmm, unless... Or look for "C:\" or somthing?

Comment: @vacip Are you sure about it because I couldn't find any "\" in this simple external workbook reference `='[Book1.xlsm]Main'!$M$9`

Comment: Look for xlsm then in the formula string.

Comment: If the external workbook is still open, it says "='[Book1.xlsm]Main'!$M$9" If you save and close the other WB, it will include the full path. But you could go look for ".xlsm]" or ".xlsx]".

Comment: @vacip so If there any extensions present in the string it's an external reference ? Yeah that makes sense thanks.

Comment: @newguy Not necessarily... We'd need more information. Maybe `ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)` can work to fetch all linked cells.

Comment: [Google found this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/953-excel-list-all-links.html) They you just loop through searching for these. Wish OP did a google search before coming to ask a question...

Comment: You may as well just use instr and search for "[". Then you can limit what range you want to search and what cells want to hightlight.